# mysqli oop return null

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Can somebody tell me what went wrong with my code :

```
class sub_category
{
    private $con;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");
    }

    function show_all()
    {
        $per_page=5;
        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        else
        {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $start_from = ($page-1)*$per_page;

        $sql = "SELECT sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori, kategori.nama_kategori, sub_kategori.nama_sub_kategori FROM sub_kategori INNER JOIN kategori ON kategori.id_kategori = sub_kategori.id_kategori ORDER BY sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori LIMIT ?, ?";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $start_from, $per_page);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $namecat, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$namecat</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='javascript:'>Update</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='sub_category.php?ghgfh=$id'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=''>Report</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
        $page_sql = "SELECT sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori, kategori.nama_kategori, sub_kategori.nama_sub_kategori FROM sub_kategori INNER JOIN kategori ON kategori.id_kategori = sub_kategori.id_kategori ORDER BY sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori";
        $stmt_page = $this->con->query($page_sql);
        $total_record = $stmt_page->num_rows;
        $total_page = ceil($total_record/$per_page);
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<center>";
        echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
        echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=1>First Page</a></li>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
        {
            if(isset($_GET['page']))
            {
                if($i==$_GET['page'])
                {   
                    echo "<li class='active'><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$total_page>Last Page</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</center>";
        $stmt_page->close();
    }

    function show($nama_sub_kategori)
    {

        $per_page=5;
        if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        else
        {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $start_from = ($page-1)*$per_page;

        $nama_sub_kategori = "%$nama_sub_kategori%";
        $sql = "SELECT sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori, kategori.nama_kategori, sub_kategori.nama_sub_kategori FROM sub_kategori INNER JOIN kategori ON kategori.id_kategori = sub_kategori.id_kategori WHERE sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori LIKE ? OR sub_kategori.nama_sub_kategori LIKE ? OR kategori.nama_kategori LIKE ? ORDER BY sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori LIMIT ?, ?";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssii', $nama_sub_kategori, $nama_sub_kategori, $nama_sub_kategori, $start_from, $per_page);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $namecat, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$namecat</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=''>Update</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='sub_category.php?ghgfh=$id'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=''>Report</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
        $page_sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM sub_kategori INNER JOIN kategori ON kategori.id_kategori = sub_kategori.id_kategori WHERE sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori LIKE ? OR sub_kategori.nama_sub_kategori LIKE ? OR kategori.nama_kategori LIKE ? ORDER BY sub_kategori.id_sub_kategori";
        $stmt_page = $this->con->prepare($page_sql);
        $stmt_page->bind_param('sss', $nama_sub_kategori, $nama_sub_kategori, $nama_sub_kategori);
        $stmt_page->execute();
        $stmt_page->bind_result($row);
        $total_record = $row;
        echo $total_record;
        $total_page = ceil($total_record/$per_page);
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<center>";
        echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
        echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=1>First Page</a></li>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$total_page;$i++)
        {
            if(isset($_GET['page']))
            {
                if($i==$_GET['page'])
                {   
                    echo "<li class='active'><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$i>$i</a></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "<li><a href=sub_category.php?page=$total_page>Last Page</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</center>";
        $stmt_page->close();
    }
 }
```

The show_all() function is working perfectly fine ! it show data and pagination with no problem !

The show() function show me data it's working too ! but the pagination gave me NULL result !

I mean the

> echo $total record;

It gave me null pagination ! is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Change `$stmt_page = $this->con->prepare($page_sql);` to `$stmt_page = $con->prepare($page_sql);`

Comment: Nope, it gave me error now :( Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\whatever\login\admin\sql\sub_category.php on line 108

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\whatever\login\admin\sql\sub_category.php on line 108

Comment: It inside class by the way and i put my $con variable inside construct function, it's working on other function but not on this one :(

Comment: If you want a function to return something use `return` not `echo`.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't want to return any value, just want to show it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysqli, but I do think you missed the `fetch` and you are confused on the usage of `bind_result`.

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Add a name (for example total) to the column:

```
 SELECT count(*) as total FROM sub_kategori ....
```

And then just echo the value:

```
echo $row->total
```

Comment: Do a var_dump($row) before the echo, and tell me what it prints.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious in that I haven't used the $this in this way in php; that is, to specify access to a global variable outside a specific class. When sharing variables across functions, $global is used to specify the shared (con in this case) variable.

 In your showAll function, you set $total_record = $stmt_page->num_rows; in your second (show) function you set $total_record = $row; where $row does not appear to have been initialized  ... hence NULL is correct.

Comment: No it's not like that. I write it only "$row" because i already bind the result of "count(*)" from the query on "$row" variable, it's how mysqli bind result works in taking value from the executed query.

Comment: I use "count(*)" and bind_result because bind_param in mysqli not support num_rows.

Comment: Right, so in your example (thanks for highlghting the bind), $row is bound to the resultset. So to get the number of rows, wouldn't you want to use $row->num_rows  instead of just $row?

Comment: bind_param in mysqli not support num_rows, that's why i have to use "count(*)" and bind_result.